# Parsing EC2 on-demand pricing from ec2instances.info

Tags: jq

I am trying to use `curl` and `jq` to parse the AWS EC2 on-demand pricing and construct a JSON map suitable for use in a Terraform module.

The script that I came up with looks like this, but it doesn't seem to be correct:

```
curl --silent --show-error 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/powdahound/ec2instances.info/master/www/instances.json' |
jq '.[]
    | .instance_type as $instance_type
    | (.pricing | keys) as $keys 
    | [.pricing[].linux.ondemand | .] as $values
    | reduce range(0; $keys|length) as $i 
        ({}; . + { ($keys[$i] + "|" + $instance_type): $values[$i] })'
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is a smaller code sample to illustrate the problem:

```
curl --silent --show-error 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/joshuaspence/0904a6ce25f8830d9ae2eac8fc44fc7a/raw/b24600ab2e536556a74f4dbb45e2ddaa432d430e/sample.json' |
jq '.[]
    | .instance_type as $instance_type
    | (.pricing | keys) as $keys
    | [.pricing[].linux.ondemand | .] as $values
    | reduce range(0; $keys|length) as $i
        ({}; . + { ($keys[$i] + "|" + $instance_type): $values[$i] })'
```

The expected output from the above command is:

```
{
  "ap-south-1|m1.small": "N/A",
  "us-east-1|m1.small": "0.061",
  "sa-east-1|m1.small": "0.058",
  "ap-northeast-2|m1.small": "0.058",
  "ap-southeast-2|m1.small": "0.058",
  "us-west-2|m1.small": "0.044",
  "us-gov-west-1|m1.small": "0.053",
  "us-west-1|m1.small": "0.047",
  "eu-central-1|m1.small": "N/A",
  "eu-west-1|m1.small": "0.047"
}
{
  "ap-south-1|m1.medium": "N/A",
  "us-east-1|m1.medium": "0.087",
  "ap-northeast-1|m1.medium": "0.122",
  "sa-east-1|m1.medium": "0.117",
  "ap-northeast-2|m1.medium": "N/A",
  "ap-southeast-1|m1.medium": "0.117",
  "ap-southeast-2|m1.medium": "0.117",
  "us-west-2|m1.medium": "0.087",
  "us-gov-west-1|m1.medium": "0.106",
  "us-west-1|m1.medium": "0.095",
  "us-central-1|m1.medium": "N/A",
  "us-west-1|m1.medium": "0.095"
}
```

The actual output is:

```
{
  "ap-northeast-2|m1.small": "N/A",
  "ap-south-1|m1.small": "0.061",
  "ap-southeast-2|m1.small": "0.058",
  "eu-central-1|m1.small": "0.058",
  "eu-west-1|m1.small": "0.058",
  "sa-east-1|m1.small": "0.044",
  "us-east-1|m1.small": "0.053",
  "us-gov-west-1|m1.small": "0.047",
  "us-west-1|m1.small": "N/A",
  "us-west-2|m1.small": "0.047"
}
{
  "ap-northeast-1|m1.medium": "N/A",
  "ap-northeast-2|m1.medium": "0.087",
  "ap-south-1|m1.medium": "0.122",
  "ap-southeast-1|m1.medium": "0.117",
  "ap-southeast-2|m1.medium": "N/A",
  "eu-central-1|m1.medium": "0.117",
  "eu-west-1|m1.medium": "0.117",
  "sa-east-1|m1.medium": "0.087",
  "us-east-1|m1.medium": "0.106",
  "us-gov-west-1|m1.medium": "0.095",
  "us-west-1|m1.medium": "N/A",
  "us-west-2|m1.medium": "0.095"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your script provides the wrong output is that JSON objects do not have a specific order by their keys, and `jq` built-ins are not stable with regards to what this ordering is. This means that when you do `(.pricing | keys)` and `[.pricing[].linux.ondemand | .]`, the order of the keys in the former does not match the order of the values in the latter.

A simplified and working version of your jq program goes as follows:

```
jq '.[] | .instance_type as $it | .pricing | with_entries(.key |= "\(.)|\($it)" | .value |= .linux.ondemand)'
```

This jq program uses `with_entries` to transform a JSON object into a JSON array of `{key, value}` objects and perform a transformation on the key-value pairs before reassembling the original object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **keys_unsorted** to preserve the ordering of the keys in the original `.pricing` object.

```
    .[]
  | .instance_type as $instance_type
  | .pricing
  | [
        keys_unsorted[] as $k
      | .[$k].linux.ondemand
      | {("\($k)|\($instance_type)"): .}
    ]
  | add
```